# active record how do I specify a column after a join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to make an sql query using activerecord and I'm having a hard time specifying a specific column from multiple joined tables.

for instance in sql

```
select go.id, sequence.name, sequence.id from sequence join (goterms,...) on ...
```

this is not beautiful sql but my point is that I'm able to specify which .id I want returned

in activerecord I'm doing this:

```
results = Sequence.joins(:Foreigndb,:Goterm,:Taxa)
.select(:header,:taxaclass, :genus, :interpro_desc,:description,:dbname,:read_depth, :name)
.distinct
```

I want to be able to get id from :Goterm but :Taxa and :Foreigndb also use id as a column in the database so i'm getting uninformative errors that I assume stem from this issue when I do the following.

```
results = Sequence.joins(:Foreigndb,:Goterm,:Taxa)
.select(:header,:taxaclass, :genus, :interpro_desc,:description,:dbname,:read_depth, :name,:id)
.distinct
```

What is the correct way to just specify that I want Goterm.id?

edit - Here is the error:
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'Goterm.id' in 'field list'

when I run:
    results = Sequence.joins(:Foreigndb,:Goterm,:Taxa).select(:header,:taxaclass,:genus, :interpro_desc,:description,:dbname, :read_depth, :name,'Goterm.id').limit(5).offset(0).dresults = Sequence.joins(:Foreigndb,:Goterm,:Taxa).select(:header,:taxaclass, :genus, :interpro_desc,:description,:dbname, :read_depth, :name,'Goterm.id').limit(5).offset(0).distinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
results = Sequence.joins(:Foreigndb,:Goterm,:Taxa).select(:header,:taxaclass, :genus, :interpro_desc,:description,:dbname,:read_depth, :name, 'sequences.id')
.distinct
```

Comment: birci I tried this, but that still returned an error: results = Sequence.joins(:Foreigndb,:Goterm,:Taxa).select(:header,:taxaclass, :genus, :interpro_desc,:description,:dbname, :read_depth, :name,'Goterm.id').limit(5).offset(0).distinct. Again with the ambiguous error

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that ilan's answer is correct, however be sure that everything is lower case. I was using 'Goterm.id' to make the selection when it needs to be 'goterm.id'

If anyone else runs into this, I also ran into difficulties grabbing the goterm.id data out of the returned query objects. Each time I called object.id on that return set it would give me something different from what I was expecting. I think the attribute I was expecting was being obscured by something else. To get the data I needed I did the following:

```
results = Sequence.joins(:Foreigndb,:Goterm,:Taxa).select(:header,:taxaclass, :genus,:interpro_desc,:description,:dbname,:read_depth, :name).distinct
firstRes = results[0]
firstRes.attributes['id']
```